# Property 'length' does not exist on type 'HTMLElement'

Tags: javascript, typescript, angular6

I am trying to loop over the number of nav-items i have. But when i am doing this, i get the error: Property 'length' does not exist on type 'HTMLElement'. I know i can change document.getElementById('nav-item) to document.getElementsByClassName('nav-item') and the error goes away. But i am not trying to do that. I was access the element through its id. Can anyone please help me with this?

```
const header = document.getElementById('applicationLinks');
const navItems = document.getElementById('nav-item');
for (let i = 0; i < navItems.length; i++) {
    navItems[i].addEventListener('click', function () {
      const current = document.getElementsByClassName('active');
      current[0].className = current[0].className.replace('active', '');
      this.className += ' active';
    });
}
```

Thank you, I am a newbie so any help would be appreciated.

Comment: offtopic: instead of using `className` use [classList](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList) and the methods `add/remove/toggle`

Comment: getElementByID give you a single element not am Array

Comment: `navItems` is a single value, `document.getElementById('nav-item')` will only give you *one* value, since you can't have multiple elements with the same id, thus, `length` property is trivial

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is the for loop.

the code

```
const navItems = document.getElementById('nav-item');
```

Does not return an array of elements. It returns a single object.

So remove the for loops.

Try this

```
const header = document.getElementById('applicationLinks');
const navItems = document.getElementById('nav-item');

navItems.addEventListener('click', function () {
      const current = document.getElementsByClassName('active');
      current[0].className = current[0].className.replace('active', '');
      this.className += ' active';
    });
}
```

if `navItems` were changed to `document.getElementsByClassName('nav-item');`
Then you would get your array of objects. That would make the for loop work.

Comment: This solves my problem of getting rid of the original error. But what i am trying to do is, have the nav-item that i am currently active on be highlighted.

Comment: The code in the for loop just looks incorrect if that's what you want to achieve, Try posting your `html` as well as all the `JS` involved..

Comment: @Mike_Smith If these are you main navigation links for the application, you could also use `routerLinkActive` to add a class when the specific route is active

Comment: @IvanS95 He could use the `ngStyle` but it would look almost the same if he kept it `unobtrusive`

Comment: Thank you very much for your quick feedback. It makes the learning experience much better for someone like me.

Comment: Sure thing, glad I can help.